# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: for any string

Tags: python, valueerror

```
def sm():
    seconds_entry_get = seconds_entry.get()
    if seconds_entry_get == type(str):
        messagebox.showerror("Wrong Input", "Please type a number or decimal")
    else:
        converted = int(seconds_entry_get) / 60
        conversion_text.delete("1.0", "end")
        conversion_text.insert("1.0", converted)
```

There is some "invalid literal" error and I am having trouble fixing it.

Comment: what happens if you `print(seconds_entry_get)` at the start of your else statement?  Does it look like a number?

Comment: `if seconds_entry_get == type(str):` does not do what you think it does, I assume what you were trying to do was `if isinstance(seconds_entry_get, str):`

Comment: This is quite wrong because `<Entry>.get()` always returns a `str`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to `int` but handle invalid inputs I would instead use `try` and `except`

```
def sm():
    seconds_entry_get = seconds_entry.get()
    try:
        converted = int(seconds_entry_get) / 60
        conversion_text.delete("1.0", "end")
        conversion_text.insert("1.0", converted)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror("Wrong Input", "Please type a number or decimal")
```